# Custom RSS Template

Tags: theming, feeds

I have a view that creates an rss feed on my site.

The view is called RSS_List. What i would like to do is to create a template to build the rss u dynamically from custom fields.

I have created a template called views-view-row-rss.tpl.php and views-view-rss.tpl.php and both do not work as expected (When loading the url it asks to download a file, and downloads what appears to be a randomly named .part file. These were both suggested under theming information.

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

I would like to create a template rather than install a module etc if at all possible.

My current template is below if this helps:

```
<?php
// $Id: views-view-row-rss.tpl.php,v 1.1 2008/12/02 22:17:42 merlinofchaos Exp $
/**
 * @file views-view-row-rss.tpl.php
 * Default view template to display a item in an RSS feed.
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
?>
<item>
  <title><?php print $title; ?></title>
  <link><?php print $link; ?></link>
  <description><?php print $description; ?></description>
</item>
```

Comment: Did you clear the theme registry by visiting the theme page and clearing the caches? Sometimes it's necessary in D6.

Comment: I have checked that in case, and the issue still remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by using a module called [Content Templates (Contemplate)](http://drupal.org/project/contemplate) to style the RSS feed. It allowed me to create a template for a certain content type.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken but the file name looks incorrect.  Also, I don't think you load views template files directly through your browser.

The first place I would check would be the 'Theme: information' section of your view to see which templates are currently in use.  It is possible you have another template overriding the one you have created.  This section will also show you 'expected' file name of views templates.

Lastly, you can force Drupal to rescan your template directory for new templates that you have added.

[image: Theme Info]

[image: Template Information and Force Refresh]